# shell script in /etc/profile.d not running at startup

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a shell script at `/etc/profile.d/pg_local.sh`. It contains the following contents:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/pgsql/bin"
```

Its supposed to load that path in the user accounts' $PATH when the system starts up. However, it is not doing that. When I start up system, and try to use one of the binaries at that path, it doesn't work. I am forced to source it:

```
source /etc/profile.d/pg_local.sh
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Permissions of `etc/profile.d/pg_local.sh` perhpas `sudo chmod a+x etc/profile.d/pg_local.sh`

Comment: I made the suggested change. I'll see what happens on reboot.

Comment: I will suggest, try, to export the variable in `/etc/bash.bashrc` file. Since this is a system wide configuration file and is loaded up for non interactive shells.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen that did not work. even when making file executable, it still doesn't load at startup.

Comment: Are you sure the PATH variable is not getting overwritten somewhere else? You can run this to see what's going on: `BASH_XTRACEFD=3 PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' bash -xlic '' 3> /tmp/xtrace-output.txt`. Then look through `/tmp/xtrace-output.txt`.